# Split in list comprehension

Tags: python, file, list-comprehension

How can i write this using list comprehension? I have no idea how to unwrap il list-comprehension.

```
for line in f:
    t1, t2, t3 = line.split(" ")
    self._list.append(Time(t1,t2,t3))
```

i've tried

```
self._tasks = [Time(line.split(' ')[0], line.split(' ')[1], line.split(' ')[2]) for line in f]
```

is there any better way?

Comment: `[Time(*line.split(' ')) for line in f]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters answer is perfect, but if your for some reason really need to explicitly name your intermediate parameters, you can use something like this:

    `[Time(t1,t2,t3) for t1,t2,t3 in (line.split() for line in f)]`

Comment: thx for answers. Using asterisk can i convert srt ti int? I want to create Time with int not str

Comment: @Tomonaga: you failed to mention that in your question. Use `Time(*map(int, line.split()))` then (no need to pass in an argument if you are splitting on whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

`[Time(t1, t2, t3) for t1, t2, t3 in (line.split() for line in f.splitlines())]`

With or without `splitlines` depends of your variable `f`

Comment: `f` is already an iterable (probably a file), so no need to split those lines.

Comment: To beef up the explanation for future users, hides a neat little trick, that `(line.split() for line in f)` creates a _generator_ of split lines, which is exactly what you want if you're not looking to iterate over the file twice to apply some processing to each split line. Really neat stuff.